# .htaccess redirect root url exclude index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the root URL only excluding index.php which is in root folder. This is what i have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/redirect/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
```

It still redirects the index.php file when manually entered!

Comment: What URL are you testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

# Condition: Only match host 'website.com'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com$ [NC]

# Rule: If request is for root, redirect
RewriteRule ^$ http://website.com/redirect/ [R=302,L]
```

As you used 301 already, you may need to clear the cache for the browser to redirect properly.

Once you are happy, and would like to make the redirect permanent, change 302 to 301.